# Gunicorn Upstart File Not Starting

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to launch an app with `gunicorn` and `nginx`and have had to double back to delete and change files a few times. This time, I ran into issues.

***I first created an upstart file...***

`sudo nano /etc/init/gunicorn.conf`

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling flowershop"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/flowershop

exec env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/flowershop/flowershop.sock flowershop.wsgi:application
```

***Then I ran...***

```
sudo service gunicorn start
```

and it started!

I had to change the name of the socket it created, so I deleted the `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf` upstart file, created a new upstart file with the same name as the last and attempted to run `sudo service gunicorn start`.

***It now returns the following error messages that correspond the the following commands...***

```
sudo service gunicorn start

start: Job failed to start
```

&&

```
sudo service gunicorn stop

stop: Unknown instance:
```

This clearly had to do with my meddling, but I don't have the slightest clue how to fix it.

Comment: I have the exact error. where you able to find a solution?

Comment: @JeyachandranRathnam I just respun my Amazon EC2 instance and started over again. It worked at that point. Sometime things just get stuck.

Comment: I had to recreate the droplet(I was using digitalocean), it worked fine with a fresh install. Oh well, at least its fixed now! thanks!

Comment: @JeyachandranRathnam Lol. Yeah, sometimes you just gotta pull the plug!

Comment: the question has some holes, since you are no longer seeking an answer perhaps best to delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is try to reload your droplet

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: What about when you couldn't restart your machine?!